# KnockoutJS and Cascading drop downs with multiple function calls

Tags: knockout.js

I am new and KnockoutJS and using SPServices to interface with SharePoint lists. I am attempting to create a cascading drop down and am a bit stuck. Essentially I have a list of locations and a list of buildings at that location. As a location is selected, I construct a CAML query to filter out what databases are displayed in the buildings drop down. Really appreciate everyones work on this site. Has helped me immensely over the past few months, just can't seem to find anything on this problem.  End state on the code below is a drop down that works for locations, but an empty drop down for buildings once displayed.

**Javascript:**

```
var bm = new BuildingModel();
var lm = new LocationModel();

var ViewModel = function(){        

var vm  = this;

vm.locationID = ko.observable();
vm.buildingID = ko.observable(); 
vm.locations = lm.getLocationsAsJSON();

  vm.buildings = ko.computed(function(){

        if(vm.locationID() === undefined){              
        return bm.getBuildingsAsJSON();
        } else {
            return bm.getBuildingsAsJSON(vm.locationID().id());
    }

  });
```

Essentially the getXXXXAsJSON returns an observableArray of buildings/locations objects from two different SharePoint lists. Note that each attribute in the objects are defined as ko.observable(). Everything I have seen shows chaining based upon a single file vice attempting to autopopulate the select box using an AJAX call as the other drop down variable (in this case locationID) is updated. The functions work fine in that the following works (just doesn't link the two drop downs):

```
vm.locations = lm.getLocationsAsJSON();
vm.buildings = bm.getBuildingsAsJSON();
```

**HTML:**

```
<select data-bind="options: locations,  optionsText: function(location){return location.longName}, value: locationID, optionsCaption:'Choose...'"></select>
<select data-bind="options: buildings, optionsText: 'number', value: buildingID, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

What I thought would be pretty straight forward hasn't been. I feel close just need a kick.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should not return observable array in computed if you want to bind this computed to select control. Computed is function and observable array is function too when options binding tries to parse you computed value it uses `ko.utils.unwrapObservable()` function to get real value but it returns another function (observable Array) instead of real data.

There are 3 possible fixes:

First option: 
Call `ko.utils.unwrapObservable()` for your `bm.getBuildingsAsJSON()` function. You computed will look as follow:

```
  vm.buildings = ko.computed(function(){

        if(vm.locationID() === undefined){              
        return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(bm.getBuildingsAsJSON());
        } else {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(bm.getBuildingsAsJSON(vm.locationID().id()));
    }
```

Second option:
Add () after calling `bm.getBuildingsAsJSON()` function. You computed will look as follow:

```
  vm.buildings = ko.computed(function(){

        if(vm.locationID() === undefined){              
        return bm.getBuildingsAsJSON()();
        } else {
            return bm.getBuildingsAsJSON(vm.locationID().id())();
    }
```

Third option:
Do not return observable array in `bm.getBuildingsAsJSON` function.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot!  I changed to have getBuildingsAsJSON just return an array of Building objects vice an observableArray and works like a champ. Thanks for the help! Just learning this and it has made my life so much easier, just don't understand all the nuances yet I suppose.